# Ctrl+K doesn't work for &nbsp; indented lines

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, code-formatting, editor

Below code is indented with 2 `&nbsp;`.

```
  <- no-break space
  <- no-break space
```

I wrote this code block manually, i.e. prepend 4 spaces to each line.

Why don't I use Ctrl+K? Because it didn't work.

- If lines are indented with 3 or less normal spaces, Ctrl+K prepends 4 spaces.
- If lines are indented with 4 or more normal spaces, Ctrl+K removes 4 spaces.

But if lines are indented with any number of `&nbsp;`, Ctrl+K does nothing.

---

I don't think 4 `&nbsp;` should be recognized as code block indentation. But if so, Ctrl+K should prepend 4 spaces to wrap with code block.

I've found this problem on editing [other's post](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/31667/1). OP seems to copied `&nbsp;` indented code from https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel.

<sub>Chrome 57 and Edge 38 on Windows 10 / rev 2017.1.6.24571</sub>

Comment: Why are you indenting code with non-breaking spaces?

Comment: @Cai I found this problem when I edited someone's post, and I don't do that...

Comment: Fair enough. I can't think of any reason to legitimately use non-breaking spaces to indent code... if you see anyone doing it again, tell them to stop it! :)

Comment: It might happen when you copy code from a site, but really, allowing this brings more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Markdown simply doesn't recognize a non-breaking space as a valid code block indentation character. Just 4 spaces or a single tab is defined as identification character.

The question which remains is: should non-breaking spaces be supported? Personally I don't think so. The use case is rare, this is how Markdown is documented to work and it has proven to work this way for years. Taking non-breaking spaces or similar looking characters as identifier don't really fix a problem.